# What happened to the search/command combo box in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In VS2012, I can't get the combo search/command back. In a previous version, 2008?, this search box integrated in any toolbar and would accept commands as well as search strings. [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1665hyw1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) suggests it is still available, but when I follow the instructions to add Find to the Standard toolbar, all I get is a stupid magnifying glass that opens a free floating search pane, that doesn't accept commands. Has anyone got this working.

Thanks

Comment: The MSDN article is accurate.  You're doing something wrong, this is not youtube.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to add the "Go To Find Combo" rather than the plain find command.